# Reading CSV in Typescript gives NaN when reading number

Tags: javascript, typescript, csv

Well, I' trying to read a CSV file with Typescript

This is my code:

```
export default class Playlist{
    public playlistId: Number = 0;
    public playlistName: string = '';

    constructor(line:string){
        const item = line.split(',')
        this.playlistId = +item[0];
        this.playlistName = item[1];
    }
}
```

```
fs.readFile('.\\csv\\playlist.csv', 'utf8',(err, res) => {
        if(err){
            console.error('YEET');

            return;
        }else{

            const playlists =  res.split('\n').slice(1).map((x:string) => new Playlist(x))
            console.log(playlists)
        }
    })
```

This is the CSV data:

```
"1","Music"
"2","Movies"
"3","TV Shows"
"4","Audiobooks"
```

This is the Playlist Object I get:

```
Playlist { playlistId: NaN, playlistName: '"Music"\r' },
```

As you can see for the playlistId I get NaN but I have no idea why because I parse it to a number correctly. Furthermore, not to neccessary the Name of the Playlist is in a weird format too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you have speech marks wrapped around each value. Either fix the `Playlist` class with the following:

#### Fixed Playlist Class

```
export default class Playlist {
  public playlistId: Number = 0;
  public playlistName: string = "";

  constructor(line: string) {
    const item = line.split(/"|\\r/).join("").split(",");
    this.playlistId = Number(item[0]); // or keep as =+ item[0]
    this.playlistName = item[1];
  }
}
```

Or, remove the quotes from the CSV file.

#### Fixed Playlist CSV

```
1,Music
2,Movies
3,TV Shows
4,Audiobooks
```

Comment: Is there also a solution to remove the \r from the playlistName

Comment: @govit19 see revised `Playlist` class in answer :)

Answer (score 0):

If you see that your playlistName, it includes an extra pair of double quotes `'"Music"\r'`.

Before you parse `item[0]`, it should also look like `'"1"'` and `+'"2"'` is expected to be NaN when you parse that.

An easy fix would be to just replace all the quotes with empty character, effectively changing the parsing to `+item[0].replace(/\"/g, "")`

Answer (score -1):

do you not put ; after each value? It's just a question?

Comment: Nope, but I've tried and still not working. And a  friendly reminder: Do not write an answer for a question like this. Just use the comment function. :)

Comment: yes you are right :) thanks

Comment: Also i can't add comment until i reach 50, but you has to know it, before you downgrade my reputation

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).